# Show a button after main window opens

Tags: c++, qt

How do you show a button 10 seconds right after the main window open?

I am using the showevent but it stucks if I do the 10 second count inside it:

```
void main::showEvent(QShowEvent *event)
{
   QWidget::showEvent( event );
   QTimer timer;
    timer.start(10000);

    while(timer.remainingTime() > 0)
    {
       qDebug() << timer.remainingTime();
        if(timer.remainingTime() <= 0)
        {
            _ui->btn_CloseAd->show();
            timer.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the solution for this?

Comment: [`Qtimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) and signals/slots?

Comment: Yes, I'm using QTimer, but the process completes before the windw shows

Comment: Don't loop in the function, connect the [`timeout`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#timeout) signal to a slot instead. Your loop will block the event loop of the program, making your program seem unresponsive.

Comment: Don't use a `while loop`. Use [`QTimer::singleShot`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot) to trigger a slot after a specified amount of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void main::showEvent(QShowEvent *event)
{
   QWidget::showEvent( event );
   QTimer::singleShot(10000, _ui->btn_CloseAd, &QWidget::show);
}
```